# Proving an inclusion map is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

I wish to prove for $p < q < r$, the inclusion map $L^p \cap L^r \rightarrow L^q$ is continuous. There is a solution to this problem here (last paragraph of #3): https://math24.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/ch6-folland.pdf
However, I cannot seem to understand their proof. Would anyone be able to break it down? To me it seems to be more of a verification than a proof.

Comment: The key is the inequality $||f||_q|\leq ||f||_p^\lambda ||f||_r^{1-\lambda}$. Do you understand the proof given this? You should try to prove it via Hölder's inequality.

Comment: @user293794 That is one of my biggest hurdles, I could not seem to see where that came from. How does that follow from Hölder's inequality?

Comment: Try choosing $\lambda$ so that $\frac{\lambda}{p}+\frac{1-\lambda}{r}=\frac{1}{q}$.